# How to accept Youtube cookies with Python requests module

Tags: python, cookies, request, youtube

I am new to Python and HTTP. For exercise I have created the small function that searches Youtube and returns search results in response object

```
def search_yt():
    import requests
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results'
    query_string = str(input('Please enter search keyword: '))
    payload = {'search_query': query_string}
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    print(r.text)
```

The problem is that i am being redirected to a cookie acceptance page with an Accept button. Here is the form

```
<form action="https://consent.youtube.com/s" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
<input type="hidden" name="gl" value="NO">
<input type="hidden" name="m" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="pc" value="yt">
<input type="hidden" name="continue" value="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Michael+Jackson">
<input type="hidden" name="ca" value="r"><input type="hidden" name="x" value="8">
<input type="hidden" name="v" value="cb.20210518-05-p0.no+FX+161">
<input type="hidden" name="t" value="ADw3F8jK04hHEDaOQ6Lo4k3iEAJmnGpVoQ:1621602104080">
<input type="hidden" name="hl" value="no"><input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="uxe" value="23983172"><input type="submit" value="Godta" class="button" aria-label="Godta bruken av informasjonskapsler og andre data for formålene som beskrives"/>
</form>
```

How do I go past this page?

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question.

I noticed that CONSENT value of a cookie is originally set to CONSENT=PENDING+int, so I tried changing PENDING to YES and it worked! For a number you can use any int => 0

```
def search_yt():
    import requests
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results'
    query_string = str(input('Please enter search keyword: '))
    payload = {'search_query': query_string}
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload, cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+42'})
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Yes, this really helped! Such a simple and elegant solution.

Comment: Great work! Thank you